# constant differential of a smooth function

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have smooth manifold $M$, smooth function $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$, and $X$ is complete vector field on $M$, such that $Xf(p) = 1$ for every $p\in M$. I am trying to proof, that for every $p\in M$, and for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$

$f(\varphi_t(p)) = f(p) + t$.

($\varphi_t$ is a flow of $X$).

What I`ve already done:

$Xf(p) = df_p\left(\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}\varphi_t(p)\right) = \frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}f(\varphi_t(p)) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\varphi_t(p)) - f(p)}{t} = 1$.

Here I got stuck. Does anyone can help me finish this out?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi_t$ denote the flow of $X$.

Observe that $\frac{d}{dt'}f(\varphi_{t'}(p)) = Xf (\varphi_{t'}(p)) = 1$.

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we get $f(\varphi_t(p)) - f(p) = f(\varphi_t(p)) - f(\varphi_0(p)) = \int_0^t \frac{d}{dt'}f(\varphi_{t'}(p))dt' = \int_0^t dt' = t$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is so annoying to get stack in such elementary stuff...